# Why is the $\chi^2$-test given it's name?

Tags: probability, statistics

This may be a silly question, but why is the $\chi^2$-test given it's name rather than just the $\chi$-test? The only reason I can think of is the way it's calculated since it requires the squaring of numbers. Is there a more meaningful reason?

Comment: From [Chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#History_and_name).

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! I didn't see that when I first looked at the article.

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: Historically, $\chi$ was used to represent standard normal. The square of a standard normal random variable has the chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom.

Comment: To be more precise, when in the multivariate normal distribution there is a density proportional to $e^{ -\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol\mu)'\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol\mu) }$, Karl Pearson wrote $e^{ -\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol\chi^2}$ as a shorthand and then in 1900 used this for the name of a related test